# Setting a Custom Paper Size in Printer from VB.Net 2010

Tags: vb.net

I  want to print on the custom paper size 180 mm * 90 mm , i am using vb.net 2010 and print document, i tried to change the paper size use this code

```
 document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = New PaperSize("custom", TextBox21.Text, TextBox22.Text)
```

its working fine in print preview but when i am printing its printing on paper size " letter " , i tried also ComboPaperSize and PageSetupDialog using this code , i chose " custom_paper1_size " in compoPaerSize and i used this code also for check the paper size in pagesetupdialog, the paper size changed in pagesetupdialog to " letter " height = 1100 , width = 850 
THis the combobox for paper size

```
    comboPaperSize.SelectedIndex = -1
     `enter code here`   comboPaperSize.DisplayMember = "PaperName"

        Dim pkSize As PaperSize
        For i = 0 To PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count - 1
            pkSize = PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Item(i)
            comboPaperSize.Items.Add(pkSize)
        Next

        ' Create a PaperSize and specify the custom paper size through the constructor and add to combobox. 

        Dim pkCustomSize1 As New PaperSize("Custom_Paper1_Size", TextBox21.Text, TextBox22.Text)

        comboPaperSize.Items.Add(pkCustomSize1)
```

This is for the page setup dialog

```
 PageSetupDialog1.PageSettings = _
            New System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings
        PageSetupDialog1.PageSettings.PaperSize = comboPaperSize.SelectedItem
        PageSetupDialog1.PageSettings.Landscape = True

        ' Initialize dialog's PrinterSettings property to hold user 
        ' set printer settings.
        PageSetupDialog1.PrinterSettings = _
            New System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings

        'Do not show the network in the printer dialog.
        PageSetupDialog1.ShowNetwork = False

        'Show the dialog storing the result. 
        Dim result As DialogResult = PageSetupDialog1.ShowDialog()
```

I lost one week now searching for solve this problem .
can anyone please tell me how to print landscope on paper custom paper size without page margins .
Thanks